# Upgrading website from VS2005(2.0 Framework) to VS2008(2.0 Framework)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, licenses.licx, emptylicenseslicx, licenseslicx

We have a website that is created in VS2005

Recently we upgraded the website to VS2008 with 2.0 framework.

While compiling the website Compilation errors are occuring i.e Licenses.licx file is not compiling, if it compile than it will reproduces an AppLicenses.dll.

In the licensing.licx file containing one class and a namespace(i.e. OSADirectLicensing.OSADirectLicensedClass, OSADirectLicensing).

The compilation error is as follows:

```
Error 1 C:\Program Files\Sharp\Sharp Developer Tools\OSA SDK\Samples\DirectOSA\ExternalAuthority\licenses.licx: Could not transform licenses file into a binary resource.  (1) : error LC0004 : Exception occurred creating type 'OSADirectLicensing.OSADirectLicensedClass, OSADirectLicensing, Version=1.0.4006.31768, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: Invalid License
   at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.CreateWithContext(Type type, LicenseContext creationContext, Object[] args)
   at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.CreateWithContext(Type type, LicenseContext creationContext)
   at System.Tools.LicenseCompiler.GenerateLicenses(String fileContents, String targetPE, ITypeResolutionService resolver, DesigntimeLicenseContext ctx)' .
```

Does VS2008 support licenses.licx or not?

We should not remove this file from website.

How can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the licenses.licx file and recompile the project.

This should solve the problem.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Install the [EmptyLicensesLicx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EmptyLicensesLicx/) nuget package, and it will generate an empty `Licenses.licx` in your project, before it gets compiled (which is all you need for it to work).